# Uncaught errors dataTable

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Can you help me about datatable? I'm using an offline lib. Here are my directories.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/tether.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/tether.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

css

- bootstrap.min.css
- dataTables.bootstrap.min

js

- dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
- jquery.dataTables.min.js
- jquery-3.2.1.min.js
- jquery.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap.js

Here is my jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tblproducts").DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
```

I got these errors...

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (view_products.php:131)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ view_products.php:131
j @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
k @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
```

Comment: There's conflict, which data tables are you going to use, bootstrap or jquery? . Why are you using multiple times jquery?

To solve: you need to keep your jquery js at last.... after the data tables js

Comment: If I use bootstrap dataTable, what files should I remove?